# How to write program to list all the function values without repeating?

Tags: algorithms, enumeration

Suppose I have a (recursive) function $f:\Bbb N\rightarrow\Bbb N$ whose range is infinite, and I want to list all the function values without repeating.

That is, if $f(0)=1,f(1)=1,f(2)=5,f(3)=6,f(4)=6,f(5)=2$, I need a program with outputs $1,5,6,2$ I need it to firstly list $1$, then $5$, then $6$ and then $2$.

My idea is: Start from $0$, firstly output $f(0)$, and then increase $0$ by $1$ to get $1$, look at what is $f(1)$, if it is equal to $f(0)$, then we do not output it, otherwise we output $f(1)$. And then look at $f(2)$, if it is equal to at least one of $f(0),f(1)$, then we do not write it out, otherwise we output $f(2)$. But so far I found my knowledge too poor to write a program in psudocode...

My attempt:

```
x := 0; 

while (n < x) 

{ if (f(n)=f(x)); 

 n := n+1; 

else

return f(x)}
```

I think maybe this code is problematic. Could someone please tell me some way to write it? This is such a minor part of my math course that we are not taught how to write psudocodes and now I feel a bit frustrated...

Other simple ways to do it would also be appreciate. Thanks in advance to you all who may help!

To sum up, I wish to see a psudocode to out put all the values of the function:

$f':\text{n↦the nth value in the enumeration that isn't a repeat of a previous value}$
 where $f$ is a recursive function. Apologize for my poor knowlege of computing. I have no backgroud of computing and even not know what is "memory", only psudocode is readable for me... And actually I just need the psudocode program to prove that this function is recursive.

Thank a lot to you all who leave answers and comments!

Comment: Keep in mind that, if the image of $f$ contains only finitely many values, after you have listed them all, the listing program has to diverge -- there's no way to check that we have listed them all, so the listing program has to query $f$ forever just in case some new value appears. This argument is not a proof, but at least can provide some intuition.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want a code in a certain programming language? Do you want just an algorithm and you want to code it yourself? As far as I understand you want to display the range of the function, so what if the range is infinite?

Comment: Seems like a programming question to me?

Comment: Hint: use memory.

Comment: @chi I read "list" as "enumerate" here, which in computability would mean that our program gets a function (index) and the index of the function value we want.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, that's what I meant. My point is that, if the "index of the function value we want" is larger than the number of distinct elements that $f$ produces, then the enumeration has to diverge. (This is not as issue per se, but something to keep in mind anyway)

Comment: @chi Ah, that is indeed true. But that's probably the "boring" corner case. I assume that the real task is to show that the image of every recursive $f$ is semi-decidable aka recursively enumerable. Then, all $f$ with finite image are immediately (and trivially) dealt with, and we can assume infinite image for the proof at hand. (All this is relevant and should have gone into the question, of course.)

Comment: " I have no backgroud of computing and even not know what is "memory" [...] I just need [...] to prove that this function is recursive." -- that doesn't make any sense to me. What is your background? You certainly know what computer memory (aka "RAM") is? If not: Wikipedia!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your task by keeping track of the values that have appeared so far. You maintain an array $S$ that starts empty. You compute the values $f(0),f(1),f(2),\ldots$, and for each value, you check whether it is already in $S$; if so, you don't do anything; otherwise, you print it, and add it to $S$.

Comment: What if the range is infinite?

Comment: This isn't a problem, since the set of values that have appeared so far is always finite.

Comment: That is only an assumption, but the OP should stipulate that the range of the function is finite.  For example, the range $f(0) = 0, f(n) = n + f(n-1)$ is infinite. Or I am missing something.

Comment: No, I disagree. The set $\{f(0),\ldots,f(n)\}$ is finite for every $n$.

Comment: If $\{f(1), \dots f(n)\}$ then that makes sense. But he says "I want to **list all the function values** without repeating. I thought he asks for $\{f(1), \dots f(n), \dots  \}$ which is meaningless unless you know the upper bound for the function $f(n)$.

Comment: I think that "list" here means "enumerate", like in recursive enumerability. Listing all the values, even with a finite range, is uncomputable.

Comment: My range is indeed infinite, so would the code I displayed output them one-by-one? I am unsure after writting it out...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really understand your code. Generally speaking we don't do code review here.